# PHP | Replace line in large txt-file

Tags: php, replace, text-files, line-numbers

I have a large txt-file, for example:
`text.txt` which contains:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
```

But I can't get any solution how to make a PHP-file that simply replaces line `4` with the content `line4` with a different text....

**Thank's for any help! :)**

Comment: Where's the code? What have you tried?

Comment: Have access to `exec` command? if yes - i know solution for large files

Comment: If file true large - `exec("/bin/sed -i '4s/.*/ New_Content_Here/' path_to_file");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use PHP's file() function for that. It will return an array containing each line.

```
$file = file('path/to/text.txt');
$lines = array_map(function ($value) { return rtrim($value, PHP_EOL); }, $file);
$lines[3] = 'New content for line 4';
$lines = array_values($lines);
```

To save it again, implode the array with newline:

```
$content = implode(PHP_EOL, $lines);
file_put_contents('path/to/your/file.txt', $content);
```

Comment: Thank's I will try it!

Comment: Mannhardtafter i run the script it

Comment: line1

line2

line3

New content for line 4
line5

line6

line7

line8

line9

Comment: Yes, wasnt that, what you wanted?

Comment: sorry for all of the comments i hit enter :)

Comment: I´ve edited my answer. array_filter with its callback will remove empty array elements.

Comment: Edited my answer again

Comment: ???? i dont undersand it...it's the same as before again... :( (Übrigens: Hallo!) :D

Comment: Hmm, let me quickly try it out by my self. (Servus :P)

Comment: It works now. I´ve added the rtrim which gets mapped over each array item. No additional newline gets added.

Comment: This won't perform on LARGE files (what the OP actually asked for).

Comment: This is the best solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could read your file in an array, remove the 4th line by removing the 3th index, and put all together back into a file:

```
$lines = file('text.txt'); //read the file in an array
array_splice($lines , 3); //remove 4th line
//or
array_splice($lines , 3, 'different text'); //replace line with different text
file_put_contents('text.txt', implode("\n", $lines)); //put the array back into the file
```

Comment: You need to implode the $lines again by newline, since passing an array is equivalent to  `file_put_contents($filename, implode('', $lines))` where newlines will not get added.

Comment: Yes, and since $lines is a single dimension array, it will get imploded by '', which would remove all newlines and save it in a single line.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have corrected my answer. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution should be like the following - 
 1. Get the contents of the text file using **file_get_contents()** function
 2. Then replace the text 
 3. Then again write back the existing data in that text file again using **file_put_contents()**

The code snippet

```
$remove_text = "text to remove";
$file_content = file_get_contents("your text file");
if(($key = array_search($remove_text, $file_content)) !== false) {
    unset($file_content[$key]);
}
file_put_contents("your text file",$file_content);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The file content must be imploded before putting to the file. My bad. :P